# custom.css en Prestashop 1.7.x no reconoce nuevas reglas

Tags: css, prestashop, prestashop1.7

estoy teniendo un pequeño problema para aplicar unos estilos CSS en una template **Prestashop 1.7**, hace unos dias todo funcionaba perfectamente, ahora que intento modificar algunas cosas del archivo `custom.css` me encuentro con este bug, he googleado bastante y todos los problemas similares al mío se han solucionado aplicando un "`!important`" a las reglas CSS, mi problema es que incluso con la declaración de !important los cambios no se están aplicando desde mi `custom.css`

***Lo que he revisado e intentado***:

*Que no existan problemas de permisos de escritura del archivo .css

*Aplicar la regla css directamente en el archivo `theme.css`

*Reemplazar todo el archivo `custom.css`

*Declarar las reglas con `!important`

Mi archivo `head.tpl`:

```
{block name='head_charset'}
  <meta charset="utf-8">
{/block}
{block name='head_ie_compatibility'}
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
{/block}

{block name='head_seo'}
  <title>{block name='head_seo_title'}{$page.meta.title}{/block}</title>
  <meta name="description" content="{block name='head_seo_description'}{$page.meta.description}{/block}">
  <meta name="keywords" content="{block name='head_seo_keywords'}{$page.meta.keywords}{/block}">
  {if $page.meta.robots !== 'index'}
    <meta name="robots" content="{$page.meta.robots}">
  {/if}
  {if $page.canonical}
    <link rel="canonical" href="{$page.canonical}">
  {/if}
{/block}

{block name='head_viewport'}
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
{/block}
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

{block name='head_icons'}
  <link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="{$shop.favicon}?{$shop.favicon_update_time}">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{$shop.favicon}?{$shop.favicon_update_time}">
{/block}


{block name='stylesheets'}
  {include file="_partials/stylesheets.tpl" stylesheets=$stylesheets}
{/block}

{block name='javascript_head'}
  {include file="_partials/javascript.tpl" javascript=$javascript.head vars=$js_custom_vars}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

{/block}

{block name='hook_header'}
  {$HOOK_HEADER nofilter}
{/block}

{block name='hook_extra'}{/block}
```

Mi archivo `_partials/stylesheets.tpl`:

```
{foreach $stylesheets.external as $stylesheet}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{$stylesheet.uri}" type="text/css" media="{$stylesheet.media}">
{/foreach}

{foreach $stylesheets.inline as $stylesheet}
  <style>
    {$stylesheet.content}
  </style>
{/foreach}
```

Mi estructura de archivos .css es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradeceria cualquier comentario que me de una idea para solucionar esto, parece ser un error bastante común en ciertas versiones de Prestashop 1.7.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que sucede en mi caso es lo siguiente, Utilizo [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) en mi sitio, no lo menciono en mi pregunta porque no encontraba la relación con mi problema.

Cloudflare acelera los sitios web de los clientes al almacenar una copia del contenido del sitio web en los servidores de sus centros de datos distribuidos globalmente, es por eso que aunque borres cuantas veces quieras el cache de tu backoffice se va a seguir teniendo el mismo resultado, se debe eliminar el caché de los servidores de cloudflare.

Para eliminar este cache:

1. accede a tu cuenta de Cloudflare (usualmente con el mismo correo donde hospedas tu sitio web, si no puedes acceder resetea la contraseña con el mismo correo)
2. Ve a la sección de caché.
3. Escoge Purge cache
4. Purge everything.

Para mas info [Purge Cloudflare caching](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169246-Purging-cached-resources-from-Cloudflare)

*Nota*: Yo tuve que apagar Cloudflare mientras estoy en modo desarrollo, únicamente limpiar el cache no funcionaba porque tendría que estar limpiando cache a cada rato.

Saludos,

Comment: para no estar borrando `cache` a cada rato en `cloudflare` te recomiendo que en la parte que llamas a tu archivo `css` lo manejes con versiones es decir por ejemplo: `archivo.css?v1.0.0.1` y ahí vos cada vez que quieras ver el impacto vas cambiando el ultimo digito y vas sumando  de a uno!

Comment: En prestashop como se hace? Gracias por tu comentario.

Comment: nunca maneje `prestashop`, solo te di una idea de como evitar el trabajo de estar reiniciando a cada rato lo de `cloudflare`, por otro lado averigüe un poco sobre `prestashop` y existe la forma de `borrar cache`  para actualizar versiones y todo eso te deje el [enlace](https://www.lucushost.com/blog/prestashop-borrar-cache/). Suerte!

Comment: Gracias Daniel por tu comentario, menciono en la respuesta que borrar caché en el Backoffice no soluciona este error en concreto, pero gracias por la aportación.